# How to prevent a personal web server from injecting an extra head, frameset, and frame tag into my website?

Tags: html, server, media-queries

I have a static website I built out as a portfolio that I'm hosting on my stepbrother's personal web server. When viewed with the developer tools, you can see that a whole new head tag has been inserted, and then a new frameset and frame tag follows it up at the top. These tags are preventing my media queries from registering. How do I prevent this from happening? The src of the frame tag is set to the server, so I know it's not from an outside source.

At the moment, I know very little about servers so any helpful information would be appreciated. I've done a search on the subject and haven't found anything related to the topic, as most of what I see is about malicious attacks or purposefully injecting code.

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552). For this, your question is far too broad. We don't know what's going on with this personal web server. The answer is to invest in paid web hosting.

Comment: But what if other people have had that same issue with a personal server and could give me a direction to look in? Getting experience with hosting and learning about personal servers is great for a person who's interested in web development.